# What is the most complete open and linked dataset to use for taxonomy?

Tags: computational-biology

I want to ask questions like 'what family is this species in, and which other species are in this family?'.

I am aware of Wikispecies/Wikidata but are there any other good open and linked databases/APIs that would be worth looking at?

Comment: I suspect that while this is a perfectly reasonable question for a computational science forum, that the people who usually hang out here are not the crowd that would likely know the answer to this. Are there computational biology forums?

Comment: I was at a bit of a loss as to where to ask this question! I could try the Biology StackExchange...

Comment: That sounds like a perfect question for http://opendata.stackexchange.com/!

Comment: @ChristianClason You're right, I didn't know about that one! Thanks for the help.

Any way that I can remove this question so it doesn't get voted down?

Comment: @Abbie There are a few links in grey below your question. You could either *flag* for moderator attention and request migration to opendata.SE or *delete* the question. (I'd recommend the latter, and to look around a bit on opendata how they like their questions -- and whether yours has been answered already -- and then ask a new one.)

Comment: I don't think closing the question is necessary -- in fact, I think that the comments here have provided a reasonably good answer to the original request :-)